# Forcefully disable template caching in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS and have implemented routing using it. I want to make sure whenever route changes template is fetched from server and not obtained from cache, is there a way I can force this to happen ?

Comment: Check this http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.in/2014/02/safely-prevent-template-caching-in-angularjs.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should hopefully work:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks your fix is working but I get following error as mu page loads:   TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAll' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8080/ui/app/js/angular/app.js:294:21

Comment: putting a null check for $templateCache helped...thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment on the accepted answer, this should be the correct code:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      if($templateCache) {
         $templateCache.removeAll();
      }
   });
});
```